# Data scraping how to correctly target element? Cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

I have a pet project that I want to scrape data from sites, I am fairly new to element selector. How can I correctly target the first row of this table?

Here is my code below. Is there any easy way to target elements using inspect and then right clicking "copy selector" in this case it was `#r4WMCJ > div > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)` but that did not print anything.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const pretty = require('pretty');

const getElement = async () => {
  try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("https://chartexchange.com/symbol/nasdaq-aapl/exchange- 
      volume/")
      const $ = cheerio.load(data)
      const table = $("#divId")
      console.log(pretty(table.html()))
  } catch (error) {}
};

getElement()
```

[image]

Comment: yup looks like it's already there I even tried static items, not sure what I'm doing wrong. Nvm I've managed to fix it. The copy selector was wrong it was meant to be tbody > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2)

Answer (score 0):

Selector was incorrect. Obtained the data with  `tbody > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2)`

Comment: Remember to select this answer as the correct one to your question.